# Can iphone users delete your app's keychain data?

Tags: ios, iphone, keychain

To contextualize the question, our use case is an app through which users can get free promotional items on signup.  We would like to prevent abuse of the system by limiting to one promotion per device.  Since we can't access the UDID, we need some other (mostly) reliable way to check if the phone has already signed up an account.  We don't need a solution that is impossible to circumvent, just one that is highly inconvenient to circumvent.

If we store a unique key in the user's keychain, then we'll be able to read it again even if they uninstall and reinstall the app.  We're considering using this method to track devices that have already signed up accounts.

Questions:

1. Is there a relatively easy way that the user could delete or change our app's keychain data?  You can assume that the user's device is not jailbroken, and that they will not go to the trouble of completely reinstalling the OS.
2. What are other options besides using the keychain we might consider?  Keep in mind that the app communicates with our server during signup, so we can store previous signup information of any kind on the server.
3. Are there any gotchas or problems with the keychain method we should know about?

Comment: Do you mean the user's device (not app) is not jailbroken?

Comment: yes, that was a typo, i fixed it now.  thanks.

Comment: Did you see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847993/can-the-user-access-the-keychain-on-ios?rq=1

Comment: @rustylepord, yes, i did, but it actually has a subtle difference from my question that is important.  The answer states that the data cannot be "accessed", but I'm specifically interested in the data being deleted.

Comment: I do not think user has access unless the device has been jailborken. Have a look under iPhone Kaychain backsup in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-SW9 Do you really need to tie up the promotion to a device or a user account, since ownership of a device could change.

Comment: @rustylepord, yes, we're already experiencing lots abuse.  Ownership change will happen orders of magnitude less frequently, and can be easily rectified with a call to customer service.

Comment: This document will help  you as well , it has how the keychain works http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_Oct12.pdf