# How to implement facebook cross-apps authorization for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, firemonkey

I'm developing mobile app for iOS 8 with Firemonkey (just for info) and my app works with Facebook. I did Facebook authorization though browser by specifying email and password. Everything works fine, but now I'd like to auto login to my custom iOS app without specifying email and password, if I **already logged in** to the **native** Facebook app.

For example, we have two iOS 8 apps: 1) **native** Facebook app and 2) my **custom** app. All apps are logged out of Facebook. I login to native Facebook app, then open my custom app. How can my custom app retrieve access token from native Facebook app for auto login?

I will be grateful for any code example in any programming language.

Comment: You have to use the native sdk and the login there. Not possible to do using the weblogin

Comment: @WizKid, thanks for the answer. Maybe you or somebody else knows, how native SDK works? Where is SDK stores Facebook access token? - Maybe in Settings App? Why Facebook app ask providing my app bundle ID - how it works? I didnt find any explanations (only how to use SDK).

Comment: The native SDK do an app switch to the Facebook app that knows who is logged in.

Comment: As I understood, I have to use FBSession methods?

Comment: @WizKid, thanks for response. I.e. Facebook native app stores access token in the protected area and SDK can communicate with it?

Comment: If you use latest versions of the SDK (>= 3.17), then the access token will be stored in the keychain.

Comment: @Ming Li, thanks. For iOS? And I get retrieve the token programmatically from Keychain?

Comment: If you use the SDK, it will by default store it in the keychain for you. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Ming Li, thanks. But how I can access to Facebook's keychain from my app, which is different? As I remember, iOS not MacOS and I cant access to keychain of the other app. Eg.: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847993/can-the-user-access-the-keychain-on-ios

Comment: It's not Facebook's keychain, if you use the SDK, it will store the access token in your app's keychain. The SDK is open source, so you can see how we do it here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk